# Can't install NativeScript for Windows 7 "Powershell is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: android, powershell, windows-7-x64, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm attempting to install NativeScript with Angular2 with no luck.  After installing **TNS**, I follow the next step which is **Step 3. Install iOS and Android requirements** in the [tutorial](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup) and run the following command:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

However, I get the following error message every time I try it:

[image]

> The error says: 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

My question is **what can I do to fix the powershell command and get this installed?** Do I have any other alternatives to install this?

**Note:** My PC is Windows 7 - 64 bit, and I have TNS installed correctly, I will greatly appreciate it if anyone know how to solve this problem. I just want to be able to install Nativescript and Angular2 and get started. Thank you!

**UPDATE 1:** I added the following to the environment variable: variable path `cmd> set PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

And I was able to finish the 3rd step on an elevate command prompt. I installed all the android components in accordance to the step, but when I went back to run the **tns** now I get the following error: `tns is not recognized as an internal or external command`

**What can I do to fix this issue? Do I need to somehow revert the path variable to get the TNS working?**

[image: tns error]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don;t have your environment path set.
You can either try to set your environment path or manually install everything needed for development with NativeScript.

For the first option you can try to set your path with:

```
cmd> set PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

And then try to run the script for the autmated instalation.

If you prefer to install everything "by hand" you can take a look at this article. Installing everything manually can sound intimidating, but at least you will have an idea what exactly you are going to use in the mobile development. When I say installing "by hand" I mean that instead of running the Powershell, you can install all the required dependences one by one (Node.js, JDK, Android SDK, Android build tools and environment path setup)

Comment: I got another error following your instructions, now that I changed the environment variable. I got the installation to work, but I don't see the android studio on my computer, and the TNS command doesn't work. See my edited question.

Comment: Well.. the command was meant to be run via your command prompt (cmd) .. the way you have set your Path has deleted all other path variables.. either revert your path setting and add it manually (without cmd set) or use the cmd with set <your-path-to-set>. Right now as all your environment paths are deleted you don't have nor ANDROID_HOME nor JAVA_HOME paths set .. not to mention other previously set paths

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the environment variable: variable path cmd

```
> set PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

This should work.